# Making variable accessible to all areas of my class

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How would I make the variable **cRentStart** in the above class accessible to all classes in my program?

At the moment I'm using **dateCheck** in form1 when it initializes, so I'd like to keep this, and go on to use it in another event called **private void viewOverdue_Click**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    viewRent.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    dateCheck();
}

void dateCheck()
{

    CurrentDate.Text = "" + DateTime.Now;
    DateTime cRentStart, cRentEnd;
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;  

    if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        cRentStart = today.AddDays(-5);
        cRentEnd = today.AddDays(2);
        CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
    {
        cRentStart = today.AddDays(-6);
        cRentEnd = today.AddDays(1);
        CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        cRentStart = today.AddDays(0);
        cRentEnd = today.AddDays(7);
        CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
    {
        cRentStart = today.AddDays(-1);
        cRentEnd = today.AddDays(6);
        CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
    {
        cRentStart = today.AddDays(-2);
        cRentEnd = today.AddDays(5);
        CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        cRentStart = today.AddDays(-3);
        cRentEnd = today.AddDays(4);
        CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        cRentStart = today.AddDays(-4);
        cRentEnd = today.AddDays(3);
        CurrentRent.Text = "Current Rent Week: " + cRentStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " - " + cRentEnd.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare it as an `internal` or `public` property of `Form1`? EDIT: Though, I'm not sure what you're asking in the context of your question title: "accessible to all private classes"

Comment: @ChrisSinclair how would this look like in the context of my code?

Comment: I'm guessing you need a primer on basic C# object-oriented-programming; essentially basic class structure, fields, properties, and the like. A quick google yielded this introduction from MSDN, a quick glance seems to be a half-decent source, definitely a tonne more available online: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308750.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a Global Variable.
See [this page](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable) on Global Variable.

Some notes:

- A public global variable would be accessible where ever that object is parsed.
- A public static global variable would be accessible where ever you have the class is exposed.
- Private global variable work the same expect they are only avilable internally by that class/object.

**Example**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public static string MyString { get; set; }

        public MyClass()
        {

        }
    }

    public class MyOtherClass
    {
        public MyOtherClass()
        {
            MyClass.MyString = "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see the added example

Answer (score 0):

By giving it the correct scope ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

At the moment, cRentStart is limited in scope to your dateCheck method. Declare it outside of that scope, with correct accessors, to access it from elsewhere.

Comment: So in other words - pastebin.com/00z4PA8M